# Share/Reload localStorage, IndexedDB, cookies between WKWebViews

Tags: ios, swift, local-storage, indexeddb, wkwebview

There is a controller with a WKWebView "Parent" that opens (pushes) another controller with another WKWebView "Child".

When `Child` modifies the localStorage, sessionStorage or IndexedDB then pops back to `Parent`, `Parent` is NOT aware of the changes and needs to be reloaded to see the new values set by `Child`.

It means that both WKWebView share the same localStorage, sessionStorage, indexedDB, but they need a refresh of the content to see the modifications.

How to share in real-time the same storage between WKWebView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The init of WKWebViews can receive a parameter `WKWebViewConfiguration` with a variable called `processPool` that represents all the web content (including localStorage, IndexedDB, cookies and so on) process.

So for the WKWebViews to share in real-time all the memory management, you need to declare a unique WKProcessPool for all of them.

```
let uniqueProcessPool = WKProcessPool()

let configA = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configA.processPool = uniqueProcessPool
let webViewA = init(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configA)

let configB = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configB.processPool = uniqueProcessPool
let webViewB = init(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configB)
```